# Jackson Deserialization fails with Map

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-modules

I have created a simple test case that shows the error.  Please let me know if I've missed something.

I have a simple interface that declares a single accessor:

```
public class JacksonParsingTest {
    public interface EventWithMap {
        Map<String, String> getContextMap();
    }

    @Test
    public void testJsonMapDeserializes()
        throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        String json = "{\"contextMap\":[" +
                  "{\"key\":\"processedAt\",\"value\":\"Thu Dec 31 14:30:51 EST 2015\"}" +
                  "]}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule( new MrBeanModule() );
        EventWithMap e = mapper.readValue( json, EventWithMap.class );

        assertEquals( "Thu Dec 31 14:30:51 EST 2015", e.getContextMap().get( "processedAt" ) );
    }
}
```

When I run this unit test, Jackson fails on parsing the json string:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: {"contextMap":[{"key":"processedAt","value":"Thu Dec 31 14:30:51 EST 2015"}]}; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: RecoveryEventBuilderTest$EventWithMap["contextMap"])
```

As you can see from the stacktrace, Jackson correctly extracts the contextMap token from the json but it fails to continue tokenizing the string.  As far as I know, the json string correctly represents a map.

Thanks,
Robin.

Comment: What concrete class should Jackson use to unmarshall the JSON to the EventWithMap interface? Moreover, a Map containing "foo" as a key and "bar" as a value is normally represented in JSON as `{"foo": "bar"}`

Comment: I am using the MrBeanModule (mapper.registerModule( new MrBeanModule() );), which is responsible for materializing POJO beans from interfaces.  And a map is an array of objects in json, i.e., [{},{},{}].  This JSON string was also created by Jackson, so I expect it's valid and should be parseable by Jackson.

Comment: That must be another side effect of this module, because [this code](https://gist.github.com/jnizet/9c7c991d0f92f6362ce7) produces `json = {"contextMap":{"processedAt":"Thu Dec 31 14:30:51 EST 2015"}}`. Maybe you should post a complete example containing the marshalling code as well, that produces the JSON.

Comment: Very interesting indeed.  So there's no array token in the ObjectMapper serializer in your case.  Mine was actually not created with MrBeanModule, as far as I know, it was created with log4j2, which uses Jackson for its JSONLayout appender.  I will investigate whether this is a bug in that implementation.  Thanks.

Comment: According to the log4j2-dev group, this representation was done purposely to make writing XML and JSON consistent: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-dev/201601.mbox/%3CCAOC1H_uwW9SfoD5CKpqOqEvYNw%2B%3DFtPNbdWWA8Qqtv567VpFxw%40mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, the problem is that JSON in question is structurally incompatible with the POJO: there is that unnecessary extra Array wrapper.

But there is a way to handle this particular case: if you enable `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS`, you should be able to get conversion for the specific case where array has one AND EXACTLY ONE value in it.